# Enable syntax highlighting in vim using colorschemes?

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting

In my installation of vim 8.1 (compiled from source) syntax highlighting is not working. The runtime path ($VIMRUNTIME) is set to

```
 /XYZ/VIM8/installnew/share/vim/vim81
```

which contains (autoload, colors, ftpligin, doc,  keymap, spells, tutor etc..)

Futhermore, vimrc also contains

```
filetype plugin on
syntax on
```

in addition, the default folder .vim also contains a large selection of colors. Furthermore,

```
echo &rtp prints:     
/XYZ/.vim,/XYZ/.vim/pack/bundle/start/l9,/XYZ/.vim/pack/bundle/start/ack,/XYZ/.vim/pack/bundle/start/FuzzyFinder
```

Yet, I am getting the error:

```
E185: Cannot find color scheme 'darkblue'
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

The colors are not highlighted. In addition `colorscheme <tab>` yields no result.

I tried various colors in the above mentioned folders but none worked. What is the cause of this problem?

Comment: Does `/XYZ/VIM8/installnew/share/vim/vim81/colors/darkblue.vim` exist? What does `:echo &rtp` print? Please update question.

Comment: it exists. Updating question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `runtimepath` seems incomplete. I would expect that it contains the following directories:

- `/XYZ/VIM8/installnew/share/vim/vimfiles`
- `/XYZ/VIM8/installnew/share/vim/vim81`
- `/XYZ/VIM8/installnew/share/vim/vimfiles/after`

These directories are part of the default value of `runtimepath`. Note that the 
first (`vimfiles`) and the last (`vimfiles/after`) might not exists when installing from source.

Check your `vimrc` for manipulation of the runtimepath (something like `set runtimepath` or `set rtp`).

If you manipulate the runtime path you should always use `set runtimepath+=` (to append) or `set runtimepath^=` (to prepend). See `:help :set+=` and `:help :set^=`.

Comment: I did not find folders "vimfiles" and "after". The share folder only contains "man" and "vim"

Comment: @wander95 True, they don't exist on my machine either (self-installed Vim). Added note to answer.